# How to solve exception "Unable to create ocr model using Path tessdata and language eng" in emgucv

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, object-detection

when i trie to build c# project(project for road sign detection system), that could build and debug without excption. but when i click button in main interface of the project, there was an exception as  **

> **"Unable to create ocr model using Path tessdata and language eng."**

and that highlighted code is

```
public void Init(String dataPath, String language, OcrEngineMode mode)
      {
         /*if (!IsEngineModeSupported(mode))
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("The Ocr engine mode {0} is not supported in tesseract v{1}", mode, Version));*/
         int initResult= TessBaseAPIInit(_ptr, dataPath, language, mode);
         if (initResult != 0) throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Unable to create ocr model using Path {0} and language {1}.", dataPath, language));
      }
```

please help me to solve this. 
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The *dataPath* must point to your "tessdata" directory containing language files like eng.cube.bigrams, eng.cube.params, eng.traineddata and so on (examples for english).

Comment: Can you share a link on where I can find the file?

Answer (score 0):

The datapath must be the name of the parent directory of tessdata and must
end in / . Any name after the last / will be stripped.

Answer (score 0):

For **version 3.x**, please copy the "tessdata" folder to the same location as your executable ( the bin folder ). And pass blank "" string to the constructor.

```
  _ocr = new Tesseract("", "eng", OcrEngineMode.TesseractOnly);
```

For **version 4.x**, you can specify the fully qualified windows path and add a "\" at the end.

```
 _ocr = new Tesseract("C:\tessdata\", "eng", OcrEngineMode.TesseractOnly);
```

In both the versions, do not forget to download and use the latest English trained data.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/main/eng.traineddata