# Initializing a Tesseract

Tags: vb.net, ocr, tesseract

I try to get some text of an image by using OCR. I have to initialize a Tesseract for that and this was my try:

```
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.Util
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure
Imports Emgu.CV.OCR
Imports Emgu.CV.UI
Imports Emgu.CV.CvEnum

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim lolProcess() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("lolClient")
        Dim snap As New CScreenFromWindow

        Dim OCRz As Tesseract = New Tesseract("tessdata", "eng", Tesseract.OcrEngineMode.OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY)

        OCRz.Recognize(New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(snap.GetFromAll(lolProcess(0))))
        MsgBox(OCRz.GetText())

    End Sub
End Class
```

When launching my code I get the following error:
"System.TypeInitializationException"
"Emgu.CV.OCR.Tesseract" caused an exception

I have googled a lot, but can't find my mistake. I've downloaded EMGU from [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emgucv/files/emgucv/2.4.9-beta/) and installed the .exe. Then I added every .dll from the bin-directory as a reference to my project. I also added all opencv_XXXXX.dll-files to my project. Then I also added the tessdata-directory to my project. I've marked all the added dlls as "Always copy to output-directory".

There are opencv_XXXXXX.dll-files for x86 and x64. I tried to swap them to x64 but those also don't work.

Does anybody see my mistake?

This are the error-messages and stack-traces:

```
   System.ArgumentException: Unable to create ocr model using Path tessdata and language eng.
   bei Emgu.CV.OCR.Tesseract.Init(String dataPath, String language, OcrEngineMode mode) in c:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-gpu 2.4.9.1847\Emgu.CV.OCR\Tesseract.cs:Zeile 226.
   bei Emgu.CV.OCR.Tesseract..ctor(String dataPath, String language, OcrEngineMode mode) in c:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-gpu 2.4.9.1847\Emgu.CV.OCR\Tesseract.cs:Zeile 118.
   bei Dodgemaster.Form1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in X:\Dokumente\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Dodgemaster\Dodgemaster\Form1.vb:Zeile 16.
```

A Hello World test-programm works fine. So it can't be something wrong with the references, right?

Comment: Can you provide the full error message including stack trace ++ any inner exceptions etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75531269/4973087

Answer (score 0):

When you have referenced the .dlls try changing the "copy to output directory" value in the properties to "Copy always"
Also try running it on 3.5 .NET framework.

Failing that try following this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqvvXJXuRYY&list=UUxAnMtjN08ryThpgYTBmILg

Really helpful tutorial.

Comment: That's excactly the video I am working with. I think I have done all the things he did, but still I get an error. "copy always" is active and on 3.5 it doesn't work neither.

Comment: And your machine supports CUDA?

Comment: That could be one problem. I have an AMD-Radeon, so CUDA shouldn't work for me. But I've downloaded a new Emgu from [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emgucv/files/emgucv/2.4.2/) and it says nothing from CUDA and is for x64, but still the same error.

Comment: Hmm, not sure I can help then i'm afraid.

Might be worth checking your new emgu install at:

yourinstall\Emgu.CV.Example\OCR and there should be a C# version of OCR in there you can maybe work from? unless it absolutely HAS to be in VB?

Comment: Yes, it has to be VB. Even some example programs from myinstall\solution aren't working. Some do, some throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

After several reinstalls of different emgu-installs I finally found one, that works. It's an older version, not the current one, but it is for x64. Having in mind that EVERY needed file/dll HAS TO be for x64 and working excactly as in the video, I finally got it work.
Seemed to be an x86/x64 issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the DPath from "tessdata" to "".

```
Dim OCRz As Tesseract = New Tesseract("", "eng", OcrEngineMode.TesseractOnly)
```

That's how I got mine to work.(libemgucv-windows-universal-cuda-3.0.0.2158)